# Finding $x$, $y$ satisfying $x+x=y$ and $x\times x=y$

Tags: geometry

> Find $x$, $y$ satisfying 
>   $$x+x=y \qquad x\times x=y$$
>   where $x$ is a positive natural number not equal to $0$ or $2$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is rapidly attracting close-votes, probably because it contains no information about what you have tried or where you got stuck. This information helps answerers target their responses to your skill level, while avoiding telling you things you already know. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: What does this have to do with geometry?

Comment: Also, $0$ is not a positive number.

Answer (score 2):

For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we get from the two equations $2x=y$ and $x^2=y$ that $x^2=2x$.

$x^2-2x=x(x-2)=0$ iff $x=0$ or $x-2=0$. Hence $x=0$ or $x=2$. But $x\neq 2$ and $x\neq 0$ by the assumption. So $x=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: Also by assumption, $x$ is positive, so $x=0$ is not allowed. (My edit to the question seems to have de-emphasized the original's more-explicit non-zero requirement too much. I'll re-edit.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If

$x + x = y, \tag 1$

and also

$x \times x = y, \tag 2$

where

$x, y \in \Bbb Z, \tag 3$

then

$2x = x + x = x \times x = x^2; \tag 4$

then

$x(x - 2) = x^2 - 2x = 0; \tag 5$

if $x \ne 0$, then

$x - 2 = 0, \tag 6$

or

$x = 2. \tag 7$

We may rule out the solution $x = 0$ since it is not a positive natural; the only possible such $x$ is $2$, *a priori* eliminated by assumption; there are no solutions.

.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$f(x)= x^2-2x= x(x-2)$,

$x$ is  a positive natural number.

For $x >2$:

$f(x)$ is strictly increasing (why?).

$f(2)= 0$, hence $f(x)>0$ for $x >2.$

Since $x=0$ and $x=2$ are ruled out ,

and $f(1) \not =0$, there are no positive naturals that qualify.